# Shocking limit when modulo 64 bit integers in PHP

Tags: php, math, modulo

quick, yet exciting question about PHP mathematical behaviour.

Why do I get an error

`<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero in [...][...]:2`

while executing the following

`pow(2, 80) % (pow(2, 64) - 1024)`

but not this one

`pow(2, 80) % (pow(2, 64) - 1025)`

It looks like PHP limits modulo operations, by using last 10 bits of the number for something else, while reaching 64 bit limit.

Anyone can explain please?

**Note**

This problem does not appear when using modulo with binary number, as

`pow(2, 80) % 0b100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

*(don't count, its 2^65)*

Comment: I think this is explained by the fact that `pow(2, 64)` will be a float, and that `%` converts its arguments to integers before performing the modulo operation. 2^64 - 1024 is exactly halfway between two representable floats, so `pow(2, 64) - 1024`, rounds back to `2^64`, while `pow(2, 64) - 1025` rounds to the next float down. As a partial explanation for your last result, `(int)(0b100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)` on my machine produces `-4096` (!), while `(int)(pow(2, 64))` evaluates to `0`. Why that binary literal becomes `-4096` I have no idea, though.

Comment: the precision of a double is 53 bits, so with 2^64 - 2^10 [-1] you are just playing around that limit. I guess that in the first case you get, in binary, a 1 followed by all zeroes, while in the second case you are not. The modulo takes that number as an integer masked by fewer bits, so that in the first case the modulo is by 0 while in the second case it's not

Comment: So the only mystery here is why the binary literal `0b100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` does _not_ give the IEEE 754 binary64 float whose value is exactly `2^65`, but instead gives the next floating-point value down.

Comment: @MarkDickinson because it has less mantisa bits than 65 ... and pow is floating `log exp` so rounding occurs ...

Comment: @Spektre: No need for any rounding here. The value represented by that binary literal is *exactly* representable as an IEEE 754 binary64 float-point number, and conversion of a binary literal to a binary floating-point value *should* be a simple process that's easy to make correctly rounded - it would be weird if something as complicated as `pow` were involved in that conversion. (Moreover, perhaps surprisingly, `pow(2, 65)` *is* being computed perfectly correctly by PHP here, so PHP gets the hard calculation right, but the easy one wrong.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson yep for the same reason 2^64 - 2^10 need at least 2^54 bits of mantissa (which does not fit into 64bit float) so rounding occur...

Comment: @Spektre: Representing `0b100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` exactly in binary floating-point needs exactly *one* bit of precision, not 64 bits, or 65 bits, or as you claim `2^54` bits. No rounding is necessary. Python manages this conversion exactly. So does JavaScript. So does PHP, when it's computing `pow(2, 65)`, but apparently not when converting from a binary literal.  `2^64 - 2^10` needs exactly `55` bits of precision to represent exactly, so yes, it doesn't fit into an IEEE 754 binary64 float. That's a totally different case.

Comment: @MarkDickinson that is not what I wrote you can exactly define `2^64` and `2^10` What i meant is  you can not represent `2^64-2^10` without rounding because FPU need to align both mantisas to the same exponent ...

Comment: @Spektre: And how does that help solve the mystery of why the binary literal `0b100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` does not give the binary64 float whose value is exactly `2^65`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ow I missed your first comments (where not visible yet) ... it happens time to time on this site that comments are shown much latter in different parts of world (probably some delayed synchronizaton). whell nagative output after int overflow is normal but -4096 is weird ... if it where internaly converting on decadic then maybe but from binary ? ...